# Hash table simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashtable

I am writing a function , which simulates a list of keys being inserted, in the order given into the hash table. The output should be a representation of the hash table as a list (the value `None` is used to represent unused position).

For example : `list_of_values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]`

I've written up a code but keep getting errors and problems, thanks for the help !

```
def hash_probe(size, key,):
    hash_key = key % len(size)   
    if size[hash_key] != None: 
        size[hash_key] = key 
    else: 
        while size[hash_key] == None: 
            if hash_key != len(size)- 1: 
                hash_key += 1 
            else:
                hash_key = 0 
        size[hash_key] = key
    return size
```

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: sure ill edit my question

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to add a new item to the hash table in the given code and solve collisions using [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing).
In that case, there are a few problems with it:

- In this portion - `if size[hash_key] != None: size[hash_key] = key`,
  you are potentially overwriting new values onto the old ones.
- While doing the first addition to the list, the code will go into an
  infinite loop.
- Although not relevant to the functioning of the code, the name of the list `size` seems a little odd.

The correct code should be:

```
def hash_probe(keys, size):
    hash_table = [None] * size

    for key in keys:
        hash_key = key % size
        # If we find an empty position, insert it there
        if hash_table[hash_key] is None:
            hash_table[hash_key] = key
        else:
            i = (hash_key + 1) % size

            # Find an unused position
            count = 0
            while count < size and hash_table[i] is not None:
                i = (i + 1) % size
                count += 1

            # If it is an empty position, insert it
            if hash_table[i] is None:
                hash_table[i] = key
            else:
                print("No more space in the hash table!!")

    return hash_table


keys = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]
hash_table = hash_probe(keys, 13)
print(hash_table)
```

Comment: it seems to run fine but its not printing any of the None at the end of the list

Comment: and yeah i am trying to do linear probing :)

Comment: just printing out this at the moment [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 13, 44, 51]

Comment: still giving the same output :/

Comment: @deans7 That's strange! I've also added a demo at the end of the answer. It's showing correct output there.

Comment: so confused its as if its just return the hash_list and not doing any other function

Comment: should I email you a screenshot of whats running ?

Comment: Sure! Instead of emailing, upload it online and give the link here in comments.

Comment: http://ideone.com/YjfYOI  never used that website before but i think its because the way you printed out the list you added another for loop at the bottom

Comment: @deans7 You're doing it incorrectly. The input list and the list used for the hash table cannot be the same.

Comment: are you sure :/ because  thought you just call the function like so list_of_values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]
linear = hash_probe(list_of_values, 13) and it should just print out the list with all the None at end ??

Comment: Yes, I am sure!! Anyways, I found another bug in the code and corrected it. Check out the new code and the demos to learn the proper way of calling the function!

Comment: I totally understand your way of calling them, I'm just calling them from a different file thats it to make it easier. so ive got like a testing file which calls the function so i don't add the for loop in it

Comment: @deans7 I think I got what you're trying to do. Give me 2 minutes to edit code.

Comment: ill give it a go now :)

Comment: No problem !! :) Just don't forget to upvote and accept it!

Comment: you have any clue :P ?? about quadratic probing ?

Comment: @deans7 Sure! Quadratic probing is almost same as linear probing. Instead of `i = (i + 1) % size`, just write `i = (hash_key + count*count) % size`, and you get quadratic probing!

Comment: thanks ill give it a go now ! I'm trying to print them at the same time together using the same name so def hash_probe(keys,size) but i wanted to add another parameter such as "linear" and "quadratic" so when the function calls hash_table = hash_probe(keys, 13, "linear") it prints out the linear program. do you have any clue on how to implement this idea ??

Comment: Yeah! Just as you said, we need to add another parameter to the function. In the code at the line I just mentioned, we need to add another `if` condition to check whether linear or quadratic was entered. What's the problem in it?

Comment: oh nah what happens is like i have to seperate hash_probe functions atm ahah and one solves linear and other solves quadratic. do you recommend putting them together in one or ?

Comment: Both options are ok.

Comment: when I'm doing it separatly like 2 functions so i have def hash_probe(keys,size,quadratic): how do i make sure that the quadratic gets called ive put in the i = (hash_key + count*count) % size but then it ends up printing the quadratic function for both the hash_probe functions

Comment: If you are making separate functions, then you don't need the `quadratic` argument. Name one function to be `hash_probe_linear(keys, size)` and other to be `hash_probe_quadratic(keys, size)`. The content of the functions will be exactly the same, apart from just that one line mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code besides some little typos and misnames variables is that you try to put every value in already occupied positions. The loop `while size[hash_key] == None:` will search for occupied cells, as it skips indices when `size[hash_key] == None` is found.

I refactored your code to give you an idea:

```
def hash_probe(table, key):
    size = len(table)
    hash_key = key % size
    while table[hash_key] is not None:
        hash_key = (hash_key + 1) % size
    table[hash_key] = key
    return table

list_of_values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]
expected = [26, 51, 54, 94, 17, 31, 44, None, None, None, None, None, 77]
actual = [None] * 13
for v in list_of_values:
    hash_probe(actual, v)

print(list_of_values)
print(expected)
print(actual)
```

Note that this is still not a real solution as it will get into an infinite loop when the array gets full.